# Date range query with mondrian and olap4j

Tags: olap-cube, mondrian, rolap, olap4j

I am using olap4j to query a mondrian cube. I have defined a standard TimeDimension in my schema xml:

```
    <Dimension name="DateTime" type="TimeDimension">
    <Hierarchy hasAll="true" primaryKey="DateId">
        <Table name="event_date" />
        <Level name="Year" column="Year" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="TimeYears" />
        <Level name="Quarter" column="Quarter" captionColumn="QuarterLabel" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeQuarters" />
        <Level name="Month" column="Month" captionColumn="MonthLabel" uniqueMembers="false" type="Numeric" levelType="TimeMonths" />
        <Level name="Week" column="Week" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeWeeks" />
        <Level name="Day" column="Day" uniqueMembers="false" type="Numeric" levelType="TimeDays">
            <Property name="DayISO" column="DateIso" dependsOnLevelValue="true" />
            <Property name="DayOfWeek" column="DayOfWeek" dependsOnLevelValue="true" />
        </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

What I cannot understand is how can I use olap4j to query a range of dates on cubes that have DateTime as a shared dimension.

Does anyone have any examples that can be shared?

Yosi

Answer (score 1):

In MDX, you can slice the results by a range of dates like so:

```
select
    (...)
where
    ([DateTime].[Month].[2] : [DateTime].[Month].[6])
```